# Create WhatsApp URL dynamically using ACF Pro from different fields

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

WhatsApp has a feature that allows you to [start a conversation from a link](https://faq.whatsapp.com/5913398998672934/).

This link will be built like this:

`https://wa.me/1XXXXXXXXXX?text=message%20here`

Where `1XXXXXXXXXX` must be replaced by the phone number to be spoken to and `message%20here` by the message that will be sent by default.

Using ACF Pro, I would like to create two fields:

- `whatsapp_phone` for phone number. This field is universal and will only be populated once on an [ACF Pro options page](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/options-page/)
- `whatsapp_message` for the message, a different one for each post.

With these two fields, I intend to generate a third hidden and dynamic URL field associated with each post and which will be used in the contact button on the front end: `whatsapp_link`

This way, the site admin would only need to fill in the number in the site options and the message in the post and I could display the generated link in the front end, for example, using the shortcode `[acf field="whatsapp_link" post_id="123" ]`.

I can create the two fields to be filled in, but I need code that solves two challenges:

1. Message field needs to be URL encoded before use
2. The `whatsapp_link` field needs to be dynamically populated whenever the post is saved or if the number changes in the theme options

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Unless the acf shortcode supports an 'encoding' parameter I'd guess you'll need to make your own shortcode to assemble the URL instead.

Comment: For 2 you don't need to save the computed value in a field, you can compute it cheaply when the page is rendered.

Comment: I would like to store the value in a field to ensure compatibility with all features of the theme which is very well integrated with ACF. This way I am sure that the theme will be able to use the data as if it were a simple ACF field. Of course, in other usage situations, this would probably not be necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can used ACF Pro and adding some custom code to your theme's `functions.php` file.

```
// Add ACF fields
if( function_exists('acf_field_group') ):

acf_field_group(array(
    'key' => 'group_60aaf3a3f3d4a',
    'title' => 'WhatsApp Fields',
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'field_60aaf3aaf3d4b',
            'label' => 'WhatsApp Phone',
            'name' => 'whatsapp_phone',
            'type' => 'text',
            'instructions' => 'Enter the WhatsApp phone number',
            'required' => 1,
            'default_value' => '',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'field_60aaf3b9f3d4c',
            'label' => 'WhatsApp Message',
            'name' => 'whatsapp_message',
            'type' => 'text',
            'instructions' => 'Enter the default WhatsApp message',
            'required' => 1,
            'default_value' => '',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'field_60aaf3d7f3d4d',
            'label' => 'WhatsApp Link',
            'name' => 'whatsapp_link',
            'type' => 'text',
            'instructions' => 'This field will be dynamically populated',
            'required' => 0,
            'default_value' => '',
            'readonly' => 1,
            'hidden' => 1,
        ),
    ),
    'location' => array(
        array(
            array(
                'param' => 'post_type',
                'operator' => '==',
                'value' => 'post', // Change this to your post type to your post_type_slug
            ),
        ),
    ),
));

endif;

// Function to dynamically generate WhatsApp link
function generate_whatsapp_link($post_id) {
    // Get phone number from theme options
    $whatsapp_phone = get_field('whatsapp_phone', 'option');

    // Get message from post
    $whatsapp_message = get_field('whatsapp_message', $post_id);

    // Encode message
    $encoded_message = urlencode($whatsapp_message);

    // Generate WhatsApp link
    $whatsapp_link = "https://wa.me/{$whatsapp_phone}?text={$encoded_message}";

    // Update the whatsapp_link field value
    update_field('whatsapp_link', $whatsapp_link, $post_id);
}

// Hook to update WhatsApp link when post is saved
add_action('acf/save_post', 'generate_whatsapp_link', 20);

// Shortcode to display WhatsApp link in the frontend
function whatsapp_link_shortcode($atts) {
    $post_id = isset($atts['post_id']) ? intval($atts['post_id']) : get_the_ID();
    return get_field('whatsapp_link', $post_id);
}

add_shortcode('acf_whatsapp_link', 'whatsapp_link_shortcode');
```

Comment: That looks like it'd work at first glance. What's the requirement to have Pro though rather than regular ACF?

Comment: The field group: does that mean you'll show the phone number on each post, where it's not used? And the computed field, which will get overwritten automatically - so there's no point showing it?

Comment: I need ACF Pro to use the options page functionality. I also already have the Pro on the site for other reasons. But I believe that the solution could be used for the free version as long as the phone number does not need to be on the options page.

Comment: // Get phone number from a specific post for acf free version 
$whatsapp_phone = get_field('whatsapp_phone', 123);  // 123 means post id

Comment: It worked very well! Thank you very much! There is just one detail: **if I edit the phone number in the options, the link is not updated in the posts**. Is it possible to do this too?

Comment: I solved the problem of not saving when updating the options page with the following code:

`// Hook to update WhatsApp links for all posts when options page is saved
add_action('acf/options_page/save', 'update_whatsapp_links_for_all_posts');

function update_whatsapp_links_for_all_posts() {
    // Get all posts
    $posts = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1));

    // Loop through each post and update WhatsApp link
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        generate_whatsapp_link($post->ID);
    }
}`